# How to get distinct output voltages in LM3914 dot/bar cimparator IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am using LM3914 for testing soil moisture content. Based on the water content, the  output of the IC needs to reflect.I am using the IC in the bar mode.

[image]

Now, the issue that i am facing is that, when the LED is OFF(i.e.OUTPUT IS OFF) and when the LED is ON (i.e. OUTPUT PIN IS ON), there is a very small difference in the voltage on the PIN.

I need 2 distinct voltages- 1)Greater than 3.1 V 2) GND(<0.8V)  since i need to connect the output pins of  the IC to a communication circuit.
Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Without a schematic diagram, there's no way anyone can understand what you're talking about.

Comment: That's better, but there's still no node or pin labeled "output". What do you mean by this?

Comment: Try looking at the other pin of the LED.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: The other pin is connected to +5 so that will tell him nothing. The chip has built-in current limiting for the LEDs so the voltage on the output pins will be 5V when off and, probably, 3.2V (5V - 1.8V) when on. He's getting a shift in level - it's just not compatible with his comms device input.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the LED you want to monitor with an opto-isolator. The photo-transistor will give you the logic levels you require - although they may be inverted from the way you would like.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKg4Vs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This also has the benefit that you can isolate the two circuits. The soil probe negative rail can not be grounded without interfering with the circuit operation.